# Angle Between Pair of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry

> Find the angle $\theta$ between the pair of vectors *u* and *v*.
>
> $u = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\ 
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}, v = \begin{bmatrix}
> 7\\ 
> 11
> \end{bmatrix}$

I already figured that I'll need the lengths of the vectors so I calculated those:

> ||u|| = $\sqrt{2}$, and ||v|| = $\sqrt{170}$

Now what do I do?

Comment: You will also need the dot product.

Comment: Have you not seen [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_interpretation) for the connection between angles and dot products?

Comment: The dot product of two unit vectors gives you the scalar projection of each onto the other. This is a signed quantity equal to the cosine of the angle between the directed vectors (when their initial points are identified): $$\frac{u}{||u||}\cdot\frac{v}{||v||}=\cos\theta$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the angle is $\theta$, then $\cos \theta = \dfrac{u\cdot v}{\|u\| \times \|v\|} = (7+11)/\sqrt{2 \times 170}$. So $\theta = \cos^{-1}\dfrac{18}{\sqrt{340}}$.